# Is there a way to restore KDE Activity after reboot?

Tags: kde, manjaro

I have been using KDE for 2 years...I have a feeling it can do lots I don't know about.  Recently discovered activities.

I have a feeling there is no way to do what I am trying to do...but thought I'd ask. Even if there are no exact answer - there may be some other KDE way for me to achieve what I'm trying to do.

- I have an activity with several windows arranged in a certain way (terminals, browser & mpv).
- I can stop the activity & when I start it again, it restores the desktop
- However if I am in the activity and restart the machine, when I log in - I am placed in the activity but all the windows, etc are gone.
- Is there a way to get the same windows arrangement?

I can always switch to a default activity before reboot - is this the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your session. In settings, enable Restore previous session. Details about saving session is answered in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633318/save-session-settings-in-kde-environment-without-shutting-down). Check if it works.